# Gauss Sums of Cubic Characters

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number, $p\equiv 1 \mod 6$, and $g$ a primitive root modulo $p$, i.e. a generator of the group $\mathbb F_{p} ^ {\times} \cong C_{p-1}$.

The element $g^3 \in \mathbb F_{p} ^ {\times}$ generates a subgroup of $\mathbb F_{p} ^ {\times}$ denoted by$H$.
$$H=\left \{ 1, g^3, g^6, ... , g^{p-4}\right \}$$
We have 2 cosets
$$gH=\left \{ g, g^4, g^7, ... , g^{p-3}\right \} \\g^2H=\left \{ g^2, g^5, g^8, ... , g^{p-2}\right \}$$
Consider the sums
$$
{t_1}=\sum_{x\in H}^{}\zeta^x,\;\; {t_2}=\sum_{x\in gH}^{}\zeta^x,\;\; {t_3}=\sum_{x\in g^2H}^{}\zeta^x,\;\; \zeta=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}
$$
Since $p\equiv 1 \mod 6$, by a theorem of Gauss there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that
$$4p=a^2+27b^2$$

Let $a\equiv 1 \mod 3$, and $b>0$, then $a$ and $b$ are uniquely determined.

Then the sums $t_1, t_2, t_3$ are the roots of polynomial
$$t^3+t^2-\frac{p-1}{3}t-\frac{ap+3p-1}{27}$$
This result can be found in the reference book "H. Hasse, Vorlesungen über Zahlentheorie, 1950. P460/P461"

But this book is in Germany and I cannot find it on line. Can someone show me a brief proof or a reference link in English to explain this result?

I also found for $p=9p'$ where $p'$ is $1$ or a prime, and $p'\equiv 1 \mod 6$, the Euler's totient function of $p$ is
\begin{align}
&\varphi(p)=\varphi(9)=6 \;\;\;\text{when }p'=1\\
&\varphi(p)=6(p'-1) \;\;\;\text{when }p'\text{ is a prime}
\end{align}
The integers up to $p$ that are relatively prime to $p$ can also be divided into $3$ subgroups $H_1, H_2, H_3$. When $p'$ is a prime, the count of integers in each subgroup is $2(p'-1)$. Generating the subgroups is not as simple as that for a prime. We may need $\left \{ g_1, g_2 \right \}$, a generating set of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times \cong \mathrm{C}_{p'-1} \times \mathrm{C}_6$.

Anyway, consider the sums
$$
{t_1}=\sum_{x\in H_1}^{}\zeta^x,\;\; {t_2}=\sum_{x\in H_2}^{}\zeta^x,\;\; {t_3}=\sum_{x\in H_3}^{}\zeta^x,\;\; \zeta=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}
$$
Let $a\equiv 0 \mod 3$, there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that
$$4p=a^2+27b^2$$
Then the sums $t_1, t_2, t_3$ are the roots of polynomial
$$t^3-\frac{p}{3}t-\frac{ap}{27}$$
I have verified this with some examples $p=9, 63, 117, 171, 279, 333, 387, ...$

I'd like to know how to prove this result.